# How to create a new Overlay using FolderOverlay - OSMDroid

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

Good afternoon to everyone, how to create or insert a new overlay on my map for each point i read from file ? 
To read the points i created a class that implements FolderOverlay. Below the code of my project:.

**GeoOverlay.java** - Where read the points from the geojson file

**MainActivity.java -** Where create an object of class GeoOverlay.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GeoOverlay overlay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        try {
            InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets().open("map.geojson");
            overlay = new GeoOverlay(is);
            overlay.getMyPositionList();
            Marker marker = new Marker(map);
            IMapController mapController = map.getController();
            for(int i =0 ; i<overlay.getMyPositionList().size();i++)
            {
                marker.setPosition(overlay.getMyPositionList().get(i));
                map.getOverlays().add(marker);
                map.invalidate();
            }
            mapController.setCenter(overlay.getMyPositionList().get(0));
            Log.d("OVERLAY","PROVAO AD INSERIRE OVERLAY \n");
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("*--- ERRORE APERTURA FILE ---*\n");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. FolderOverlay acts as container for other overlays. So the correct answer is probably: "No it isn't". Maybe try to reformulate your question, so we know, what you really want to do. Also, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, i I have reformulated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the GeoOverlay class as overlay at all, so you probably don't need it to extend FolderOverlay.

The main problem in your code is, that you are creating one instance of Marker and you just change it's position.

You should crate new marker for each position in your list.

```
 IMapController mapController = map.getController();
 for(int i =0 ; i<overlay.getMyPositionList().size();i++)
 {
     Marker marker = new Marker(map);
     marker.setPosition(overlay.getMyPositionList().get(i));
     map.getOverlays().add(marker);
 }
 mapController.setCenter(overlay.getMyPositionList().get(0));
 map.invalidate();
```